# Printing a list of prime factors in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to print a table that shows the prime factor counts of a certain number. I have a function to determine if a number is prime:

```
def isPrime(n):
    p1 = factors(n)
    if len(p1) == 1:
        return True
    return False
```

And a function to count the factors of a number into a dict object:

```
from collections import Counter
def factorCounts(n):
    a = factors(n)
    Counter(a)
    return dict(Counter(a))
```

Here's what I came up with for the table, but I cannot figure out how to use the if else statement to skip over a certain "i" if it is not prime:

```
def printTable(n):
    for i in range(1,n):
        if isPrime(i) == True:
            return factorCounts(n)
        del(i)
        print(str(n).rjust(5), '*' * 7)
```

This is the output for the above code. Obviously, it's not deleting an i if it is not prime, and it's not formatting the output into a table.

```
printTable(10)
{2: 1, 5: 1, 10: 1}
```

Output should look like this: (where the stars represent how many times the prime is a factor of the number "n" and the dashes represent not a factor of "n")

```
2 **
3 *
5 -
7 -
11 -
```

Comment: You need to indent the del(i) command inside the for loop. At the moment when the if condition don't match control doesn't go to del(i) statement.

Comment: How does the indentation in your actual code compare to the indentation in the question? It needs fixing in the question. If it's the same you never could have run it.

Comment: I tried both ways, but still get the same output of {2: 1, 5: 1, 10:1} for printTable(10)... obviously 10 is not prime.